# Android Spinner Customised design

Tags: android

Are there any possibilites to utilise spinner customized designs like the below picture? 
this is my spinner xml

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/service"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I'm interested in achieving this with Android.

[image]

Comment: so you just want your select service spinner to be customised.

Comment: @A.R.yes.Is there anything wrong in my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: You need an image say "spinner_bg.png", like this.

[image]

Second: Set this image as background to you spinner like this.

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/service"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
        android:textColor="#000" />
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Better if you use a **9 patch**. So you can define which areas are stretchable and which ones are fixed.